# Can defining size_t in my own namespace create ambiguity or other bugs?

Tags: c++, namespaces, type-alias, name-lookup

I have the following code which defines `size_t` equivalent to `std::size_t` and `::size_t` if I included `<cstddef>`.

```cpp
// h.hpp
namespace N {
  using size_t = decltype(sizeof(int));
}
```

```cpp
// a.hpp
#include <h.hpp>
namespace N {
  class C {
    size_t size() const;
  };
  void f(size_t);
}
// ^^^ These use N::size_t!
```

**Is this violating the C++ standard in any way and can this cause any bugs in any code that uses both these headers and any other standard header that defines `std::size_t` and `::size_t`?** I would consider it a bug too if someone couldn't use `std::size_t` and `N::size_t` interchangably in any context or if using just `size_t` in any context would cause any ambiguities.

```cpp
// someOtherFile.cpp
#include <a.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
namespace N {
  // Can there be any problem here? (Inside N::)
}
// Or here? (Outside N::)
```

My guess would be no because both my and the standard `size_t` are just type aliases to `unsigned long (long) int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your alias will not cause any issue. It appears in its own namespaces scope, so the alias declaration isn't going to re-declare anything. And even if client code is going to be irresponsible and do something naughty like:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace N;

size_t foo;
```

That is still fine, since `size_t` is the same type, regardless of which namespace the alias came from. Name lookup fails only if the same name from different namespaces refers to *different* entities:

> **[namespace.udir]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#6) If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different
>   namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do
>   not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed.

An "entity" according to the C++ standard covers a broad range of things, including types. And that is the sticking point, because a type alias is not a type, it's only a new name for an already existing type. So the two (unqualified) aliases name the same thing.